# How to create button with blurred drop shadow in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I know this question is a duplicate, but I have not found the answer. So, is it possible to create a barely visible blurred shadow from a button in Android Studio? I found an example of a button with the shadow I need. How to make such a shadow so that it is adaptable to each size of the button? Thx.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have few ways to achieve this. easiest would be to create 9-patch from an image, read carefully how to in official [DOC](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch). most pro would be to write own blurring code with probably most efficient for this purpose RenderScript. [IN HERE](https://ssaurel.medium.com/create-a-blur-effect-on-android-with-renderscript-aa05dae0bd7d) you can find useful article how to blur images with this tool

you can always implement common [material-design-styled](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html) `Button` using `elevation`/`translationZ` for increasing size of rendered-by-default shadow, but afaik there is no option for changing its color...